# How to play video in web page directly from android phone using sockets in java?

Tags: android, websocket, video-streaming

I want to do live video streaming from android mobile to pc web application using sockets. But i am not familiar with sockets, can anyone give some ideas or samples to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.

As per your question you want to implement something like video calling using peer-to-peer connection.

There is no inbuilt functionality in Android SDK. But yes this is possible that you asking.

There is an open source project by google team "WEB-RTC" (web real time communication).

It is to complex to implement but it is not impossible.

Here I am posting some use-full links.

[Getting started With WEB-RTC](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started)

[WEB-RTC native source code](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/)

[Experience working demo of video call](https://apprtc.appspot.com)

[WEB-RTC forum support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc)